# Determine the height of dynamic component

Tags: jquery, css, jsf

I have a two columns page layout. The left column display images inside a list using `dataTable`, so the height of the `div` container is unknown. The right column is just and empty `div` with border. But I have this right `div` container to be as tall as the left container. Is there a way to accomplish this? Here is my layout

```
<div id="pdfCol"> 
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable value="#{myBean.imgageList}" var="item">
            <p:column style="border-bottom: 2px solid red;">
                <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/#{item}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</div>
<div id="noteCol">

</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
#pdfCol{    
    float: left;
    width: 930px;   
}

#noteCol{
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 3000px;      
    position: relative;    
}
```

so right now, the height of the right column is `3000px`, if there are **not** many images, then the right column is too tall, and vice versa, the right column will be too short, if we have many images. Is there a way to make their height equals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this jQuery after the columns load:

```
$('#noteCol').css('height', $('#pdfCol').height());
```

Comment: I am sorry to border you again, but your way only way work for FireFox. This does not work for Chrome and Safari. And I am not sure about IE. Do you have a cross-browser solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some CSS ways of having equal-height columns:

http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

I like the One True Layout Method.