# Getting Equal Height Columns jQuery Plugin and Disqus to Play Nice

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, disqus

I decided that a JS solution ([The EqualHeights Plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/)) to equal height columns would probably be best in this case, but I'm having trouble with Disqus. As you probably already know, Disqus loads asynchronously. That's great and all (well, not really), but because the comments are loading after everything else, including the plugin, they're being chopped off. I can't figure out how to get around this. I actually tried a CSS "hack" to get equal height columns, hoping it wouldn't conflict with Disqus, but I didn't have any luck there either.

Thanks in advance, guys. You're always invaluable here.

Disqus Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var disqus_url = "{Permalink}"; var disqus_title ="{block:PostTitle}{PostTitle}{/block:PostTitle}";</script>{block:Permalink}<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /**
    * var disqus_identifier; [Optional but recommended: Define a unique identifier (e.g. post id or slug) for this thread] 
    */
  (function() {
   var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
   dsq.src = 'http://escapology.disqus.com/embed.js';
   (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript=escapology">comments.</a></noscript>
{/block:Permalink}<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_shortname = 'escapology';
(function () {
  var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
  s.src = 'http://escapology.disqus.com/count.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
}());
</script>
```

Comment: how are you loading disqus? Post some of your code used to call disqus, and we can help you defer execution of your jquery code until after disqus is loaded...also, see this recent question for alternatives to equal height columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808254/determine-the-height-of-dynamic-component/5808601#5808601

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. Like I said, I'm leaning toward JS on this one, but I'm still open to a CSS fix. Also, added the Disqus code.

Answer (score 0):

You can defer the plugin execution until after disqus is loaded. Here's how you'd do it for one of your disqus threads. Do this for each one:

```
(function() {
var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
dsq.src = 'http://escapology.disqus.com/embed.js';
var done=false;
dsq.onload=dsq.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
        done=true;
        //CALL YOUR EQUAL HEIGHTS JQUERY CODE HERE
        dsq.onload = dsq.onreadystatechange = null;
      }
    };
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

Comment: I called the Equal Heights code where you said. The jQuery code works fine, but now the Disqus comments aren't showing up at all. Maybe I'm just being dense here. This is the original code for the equal heights script: `$(function(){
        $('.equal').equalHeight();
    });`

Comment: oops, I made a mistake when re-writing the code for you. This line: `dsq.onload=script.onreadystatechange = function(){` needs to be `dsq.onload=dsq.onreadystatechange = function(){`. I was using the code from one of my projects where I had a variable called 'script', but you don't. I've updated the answer. Try the new version.

Comment: Now the comments are working just fine, but the jQuery code isn't. Do I need to change the jQuery code? Sorry, seems like Disqus makes everything more complicated.

Comment: Does your jQuery do what you want without disqus? You need to make sure that the code works, because the solution I've provided certainly will not break anything. But if it didn't work to start with, it won't work now. Post your HTML and the code that makes the equal height columns and we can take a look at that.

Comment: Yeah, it works if I `display:none` the comments. You can check out the HTML [here](http://andrew-west.com/escapology%20html). The actual jQuery code is [here](http://andrew-west.com/jquery.equalheights.js). I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: You've inserted your code incorrectly. This: `<script type="text/javascript">        
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".equal").equalHeights();
});
</script>` should be replaced by just `$(".equal").equalHeights();`...when I said `//call your jquery equal heights code here` I meant JUST the code. Don't wrap it in any script tags.

Comment: I didn't have it double nested script tags when I tried it. I may have  accidently done that when I was reverting it, sorry about that. I updated it. You can see the test site [here](http://www.andrewssandbox.tumblr.com).

Comment: I took a look at the source, and I couldn't find any implementation of my suggestion. I did see a call to equalHeights at the top after jQuery's document ready. So I can't really help you debug this. I suggest that you (1) remove ALL current calls to equalHeights (2) implement my suggestion, placing your equalHeights inside the appropriate code block as indicated. Then provide a link to this variation and we can take a look at it.

Comment: I removed the call to equalHeights at the top, but I was already implementing your suggestion in the source. You may need to view the source on permalink pages to view it though (using Disqus on a Tumblr-hosted blog). You can view my Disqus code directly (including your solution) [here](http://www.andrew-west.com/disqus_code).

Comment: Try putting your call to equalheights inside a `$(window).load(..)`. I suspect that we are calling the equalheights BEFORE all elements have been populated, even though the disqus script has been already loaded. Using $(window).load() will cause the equal heights plugin to run after every image and element has been loaded.