# How to set equal heights to a div layout with jQuery and Disqus commenting system

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, html, disqus

I have a layout that's based on div's, and uses jQuery and a "setEqualHeights" function (below) to make all the columns in my layout equal.

**Equal Heights jQuery:**

```
function setEqualHeight(columns) 
{
    var tallestcolumn = 0;
    columns.each(
    function() 
     {
          currentHeight = $(this).height();
          if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn) 
          {
                tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
          }
    }
    );
    columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}

$(window).load(function() {
    setEqualHeight($(".coln_equalize"));
});
```

**And the HTML would be something like this:**

```
<div id="wrap">

  <div id="nav-coln" class="coln_equalize">
  ... navigation ...
  </div>

  <div id="content" class="coln_equalize">
  ... content ...
  </div>

</div>
```

### The setEqualHeights works fine until I add Disqus to the mix.

It seems to be loading asynchronously, causing the heights of the layout to break up and NOT be equal anymore.

**The HTML code with Disqus:**

```
<div id="wrap">

  <div id="nav-coln" class="coln_equalize">
  ... navigation ...
  </div>

  <div id="content" class="coln_equalize">

      ... content ...

      <div id="disqus_thread">
        ... disqus stuff ...
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Sometimes I'll refresh and it's fine, and sometimes I'll refresh and it breaks up again.
Also, when I add a new comment, and that new comment appears on the page (thus adding more height), the layout breaks again.

My guess is that setEqualHeights is being applied before Disqus fully finishes loading.  And it doesn't help that the new comments are adding more unknown height variables.

Is there a way to force Disqus to completely finish loading before applying setEqualHeights?

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION #1 (but failed): Only load setEqualHeights function AFTER Disqus has been fully loaded**

I have searched for similar issues, and so far I came up with this thread:
[Getting Equal Height Columns jQuery Plugin and Disqus to Play Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853440/getting-equal-height-columns-jquery-plugin-and-disqus-to-play-nice)

But the 'solution' (or lack thereof) did not work for me.  There was mention of a way to force Disqus to finish loading before applying the heights function...but it didn't work when I tried the code.

I've pasted my attempt below:

```
function setEqualHeight(columns) 
{
    var tallestcolumn = 0;
    columns.each(
    function() 
     {
          currentHeight = $(this).height();
          if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn) 
          {
                tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
          }
    }
    );
    columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}

(function() {
var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
dsq.src = 'http://escapology.disqus.com/embed.js';
var done=false;
dsq.onload=dsq.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
        done=true;
        //CALL YOUR EQUAL HEIGHTS JQUERY CODE HERE
            $(window).load(function() {

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setEqualHeight($(".coln_equalize"));
                });

            });
        // (END) CALL YOUR EQUAL HEIGHTS JQUERY CODE HERE
        dsq.onload = dsq.onreadystatechange = null;
      }
    };
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION #2 (also failed): Get height of Disqus block using jQuery, then adding it as a CSS height parameter using jQuery**

Then I thought I might use a simpler script that would get the height of Disqus, and apply it as CSS using jQuery.
To do this, I inserted the following code in place of the "//CALL YOUR EQUAL HEIGHTS JQUERY CODE HERE" block:

```
$(window).load(function(){
          var dynamic_height = $('div#disqus_thread').height();
          $('div#disqus_thread').css({'height':dynamic_height+'px'});
});
```

But, again, I believe this attempt fails because it's also being applied before Disqus fully completes loading, and it also fails because it doesn't catch the new 
heights being added with new comments.

ANY help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Also, this might be considered related to the idea of using "lazy loading" with equal heights in jQuery.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution would be to run your column-height equalizer on an interval.  It's not exactly pretty, but it would work.

Comment: @DanielMendel How do you mean "on an interval"?  In a loop..?

Comment: Yeah, on a loop. It works like this: `setInterval(function(){ // do stuff }, 500);`.  That would fire the function every 500 milliseconds.   It works exactly the same as `setTimeout`, so you can go `var looping = setInterval(someFunction, 500)` and then to stop the loop `clearInterval(looping);`